# Ingest Avro from Apache Flume sink to Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, avro, flume

If possible to get the Avro as flow file from apache flume sink? I have no idea which processors I should use. Tried use site-to-site, ListenTCPRecord, but seems not work. Note that Flume and NIFI are hosted in different server.

Comment: I think flume's Avro sink uses Avro RPC and NiFi does not have a listener that uses Avro RPC. If there is a flume sink that uses TCP then it could probably send to NiFi's ListenTCP/ListenTCPRecord.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, if you means we have no way to get Flumes's Avro sink directly using Apache NIFI? I tried to lookup the doc, found there was Flume related processors like executeFlumeSink. But it was no longer in the current version (1.11.4)

Comment: I am saying it would be better if you created Avro and used a different sink to connect to nifi, for example it looks like Flume has an http sink which could connect to NiFi's ListenHttp or HandleHttpRequest - https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#http-sink